# Ever since I updated Visualstudio for mac, I can't deploy my app to a real iOS device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I updated my VS for mac to a stable release version (17.3.6 Build 20)
Then I opened my Xamarin.Forms solution as usual, to deploy and continue working on it.
I received a message from the IDE telling me that I can't build because I need Xcode version 14.

I then updated xcode to version 14.0.1 (Latest Stable version), and bam, I couldn't build the app because VS for mac constantly threw this error (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15955) After hours of reaserch, I eventually came across the GitHub issue above, saying that a work around was to set the linket to SDK only.

I did change the linker option, the error above disappeared, but when I deploy the app to my device, I get another erro (Yay) as you can see below: **Waiting for the debugger to connect to ...** This goes for ever, but the app never gets deployed.

Then, I researched for hours again and found a tip that mentioned I should upgrade the test device. I upgraded to the latest iOS 15 release, but the error persisted, I then upgraded to iOS 16, and it still persists.

I downloaded Xcode 14.0 thinking it might help, and told xamarin to use it to build, but nothing has changed! this still persists.

I've spent too much time on this can someone help please ?
This is very frustrating.

[image]

Comment: So you are using VS mac and you are not able to deploy to any real devices? Also, the correct XCode version is 13.4

Comment: Yes, my xcode version is 14.0 I added every detail about my VS version here : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16182#issue-1389589254

Comment: @DamienDoumer, I have same problem. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Developer Mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device) was introduced in iOS16, and now configuring the device requires turning on the developer mode in the device. Enable Developer Mode go to **Settings** > **Privacy & Security** on the iOS device. Scroll down to the Developer Mode list item and navigate into it. To toggle Developer mode, you can use the “Developer Mode” switch.

Comment: I did that already, but it changed nothing.

Comment: You could try to downgrade Xcode (Go to downloads page in the Apple Developer Portal, sign in with your apple developer account, select Xcode13.4.1 to download and install). Then you can open Xcode, go to Preferences > Location > Command Line Tools, and make sure to select version 13.4.1.